# Error:10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [] in filter

Tags: angularjs

in my program iam displaying a list of images. And then iam filtering it with a tag name. 
So here is my filter.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function()
  {

var filtered = [];
return (function(items, text)
{


    if (text === undefined)
    {
        return items;
    }
    else
    {
        angular.forEach(items, function(value, key)
        {
            var sample = value.tag;
            angular.forEach(sample, function(value1, key)
            {

                    if (text === value1)
                {
                    filtered.push(value);
                }

            });

        });

    }
    return filtered;
})
     });
```

And the html is:

```
          <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in outputphotos| myFilter:text">
            <a href="#displayimage/{{x.imageId}}"><img ng-src="{{x.url}}"></a>

         </li>
     </ul>
```

And in the output it will filter one time. But if second time i enter a tag then it wont filter.
And shows an error in console
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: x in outputphotos| myFilter:text key: object:004

I dont know how to change this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me take a wild guess, move your filtered array declaration  `var filtered = [];`  inside the return statement, something like

```
return (function(items, text)
{
    var filtered = [];
```

I believe you are not clearing the old filter and try to update the filter array which is triggering the watch again. You repeat is bound to `filtered` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Angular.js:

function $RootScopeProvider() {
  var TTL = 10; // Increase the value of TTL, default value is 10